# Shape map with a merged vector layer not working in power BI

Tags: qgis, power-bi

I merged two shapefiles—one of school districts and one for intermediate school districts. I went through every imaginable step to make sure the attribute fields were the same for both layers. I then converted it into a topojson file and imported it into Power BI. I made sure the my data had matching map keys in the topojson file. When I go to create my map, K-12's show up fine, ISDs won't show up at all, even if I try to map them on their own. Is there any way to make this work?

Steps taken:

1. Downloaded two shape files from the Michigan Open GIS Data portal (http://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/school-districts-v17a; http://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/intermediate-school-districts-v17a/data)
2. Loaded them into QGIS and merged the two layers into one layer, exported as a new shapefile.
3. Loaded merged shapefile into mapshaper, exported as topojson file.
4. Chose the shape map visual in power bi, added my merged topojson file as the map. Location name is the same in the attributes table and my main data table that I'm trying to visualize, so is the district code.
5. When I add the school district name for K-12 districts everything shows up fine. If I try to make a map of ISD districts only, nothing shows up. It's like it doesn't recognize that they're joined even though there are linked attributes in both sources.

[image: Map associated with ISDs]

[image: Map associated with K-12s]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: please describe your steps - you have no idea how imaginative we can be

Comment: Thanks Ian, just added steps and some screenshots.

Comment: what exactly did you do at step 2 Loaded them into QGIS and merged the two layers into one layer, exported as a new shapefile.

Comment: I loaded the two shape files, I could see both layers in the layers panel. I went to the vector menu, chose merge shapefiles to one, saved as a new shapefile. I checked this by importing the merged shapefile into QGIS and inspecting the attributes to make sure all of my records were included, which they were.